# Using Canvas to position different sized squares

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to create a background that is inspired by this art work http://www.artinthepicture.com/paintings/Paul_Klee/Flora-on-the-Sand/

This is my code so far https://github.com/jessicacgu/jessicacgu.github.io/blob/faces/index.html

I'm using javascript instead of CSS because I wanted each square to have a facial expression that blinks (changes between happy and excited) (if there's something cooler to do, please let me know!)

Right now I have all the squares as the same size and equally spaced between each other. I want it to be more like the art piece by having different shaped squares.

My problem is that if I draw a square at 0,0 to be 15x15, how do I figure out that the other squares cannot overlap the first square? Is this possible?

If not, I can get rid of the expressions and just use CSS (I mainly want to imitiate that artwork :( ).

^Also, what's the right way to showcase large pieces of code on stackoverflow? Should I copy and paste or post link to github or put in codepen?

**EDIT:** The code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="application/javascript">
      // Draws faces onto all of the canvas. Puts 10px distance between each
      // face
      function draw_faces() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("faces_bkgd");
        canvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        if (canvas.getContext) {
          var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
          // Setting a background color
          ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(244,191,175)";
          ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
          // Creating the shape of the face
          var shape = new Path2D();
          shape.rect(0,0,30,30);
          // Making the Happy Expression
          var happy_expr = new Path2D();
          // Making the left eye (as a carrot shape)
          happy_expr.moveTo(4,13);
          happy_expr.lineTo(8,5);
          happy_expr.lineTo(12,13);
          // Making the right eye (as a carrot shape)
          happy_expr.moveTo(18,13);
          happy_expr.lineTo(22,5);
          happy_expr.lineTo(26,13);
          // Making the mouth (a thin line)
          happy_expr.moveTo(8,22);
          happy_expr.lineTo(22,22);
          // Making the Excited Expression
          var excited_expr = new Path2D();
          // Making the left eye (90 deg clockwise carrot)
          excited_expr.moveTo(3,5);
          excited_expr.lineTo(11,9);
          excited_expr.lineTo(3,13);
          // Making the right eye (90 deg counter clockwise carrot)
          excited_expr.moveTo(26,5);
          excited_expr.lineTo(18, 9);
          excited_expr.lineTo(26, 13);
          // Making the mouth (a W shape)
          excited_expr.moveTo(7,17);
          excited_expr.lineTo(11,25);
          excited_expr.lineTo(15,17);
          excited_expr.lineTo(19,25);
          excited_expr.lineTo(23,17);
          // Colors for the faces. Along with the background creates a palette
          // that was taken from
          // http://www.colourlovers.com/palette/1959912/L_i_n_d_a
          var colors = ["rgb(211,210,164)", "rgb(198,223,194)",
          "rgb(217,194,152)"];
          // Expressions for the faces
          var exprs = [happy_expr, excited_expr];
          // Keeps track of the colors for each face drawn onto the canvas
          var faces_color = [];
          // Keeps track of the expressions for each face drawn onto the
          // canvas
          var faces_expr = [];
          // Scaling the faces by 2x. Adjusting for new number of faces on
          // canvas
          ctx.scale(2, 2);
          var num_width = canvas.width/70;
          var num_height = canvas.height/70;
          // Does actual drawing of  face onto the canvas
          function draw_face(x, y, color, shape, expr) {
              ctx.save();
              ctx.translate(x, y);
              // Drawing the shape of the face
              ctx.fillStyle = color
              ctx.fill(shape);
              // Giving the face a border
              ctx.lineWidth = 3;
              ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(176,144,132)";
              ctx.strokeRect(0,0,30,30);
              // Drawing the expression
              ctx.lineWidth = 1;
              ctx.stroke(expr);
              ctx.restore();
          }
          // Setting up the colors and initial expressions for each face
          for (var i = 0; i < num_width ; i += 1) {
            for (var j = 0; j < num_height ; j += 1) {
              // Math.floor(Math.random()*100) chooses a random number from an
              // even distribution of the integers[0,100)
              var c = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)%colors.length;
              var e = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)%exprs.length;
              // Draw the initial face on the canvas
              draw_face(i*40,j*40, colors[c], shape, exprs[e]);
              // Keeps track of each faces's color and expression
              faces_color.push(c);
              faces_expr.push(e);
            }
          }
          // Changes the expressions of a few random faces at a time
          function change_facial_expr() {
            var face_num = 0;
            // Chooses a random face to change
            var blink = Math.floor(Math.random() * faces_color.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < num_width; i += 1) {
              for (var j = 0; j < num_height ; j += 1) {
                // Determines if the face is to be changed
                if (face_num == blink) {
                  faces_expr[face_num] = (faces_expr[face_num]+1)%exprs.length
                }
                draw_face(i*40, j*40, colors[faces_color[face_num]], shape,
                    exprs[faces_expr[face_num]]);
                face_num += 1;
              }
            }
          }
          window.setInterval(change_facial_expr, 1000);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="draw_faces();">
    <canvas id="faces_bkgd"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could get a similar effect to the painting by dividing the canvas into squares, and then further sub-diving into a random numbers of equally spaced squares.  If you want the exact number of squares on the painting you could specify the relative positions in an array and scale to the width and height.

Comment: @brenzy I see. Thank you!